# Java - Is new Stack<?>[N] equivalent to new Stack[N] for generic data type Stack<Item>?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, unbounded-wildcard

Is `new Stack<?>[N]` equivalent to `new Stack[N]` for a generic data type `Stack<Item>`?

EDIT: While I understand that mixing generic types and arrays should best be avoided and that more robust solutions exist, my query still stands: widely recognized textbooks such as *Algorithms, 4th Edition* by Kevin Wayne and Robert Sedgewick (pg. 158) suggest using constructs like the following:

```
Stack<String>[] a = (Stack<String>[]) new Stack[N];
```

Comment: Fast non-answer: don't do it. Generics and arrays should not be used together. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Comment: @EddyG, I was hoping to create a stack of strings with the following code: Stack<String>[] a = (Stack<String>[]) new Stack[N]; It produces a warning but is this always considered bad practice?

Comment: Again; all you need to know is in the documentation from Oracle. Instead of using arrays, just go for collections types, like ArrayList. Then it is straight forward to create an "ArrayList<Stack<String>>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, except for the return type (one is `Stack[]`, the other is `Stack<?>[]`).

Note that `Stack[]` can be assigned to `Stack<String>[]` without an explicit cast (you will just get an unchecked conversion warning), whereas it is an error to assign a `Stack<?>[]` to `Stack<String>[]` without a cast.

`new Stack[N]` uses a raw type which is not recommended in new code.

Comment: No they are not equivalent. The first is not legal Java and will not compile. The second is and will.

Comment: @EJP: It is absolutely valid Java.

Comment: @EJP, You're [wrong](http://ideone.com/6ibLd3). I suggest you remove your comment.

Answer (score 2):

[ Turning my comment into a real answer ]

1) Mixing arrays and generic types should be avoided.

2) Instead, one can use Java Collection types, for example ArrayList when the need comes up to handle multiple "generic" objects, like in

```
ArrayList<Stack<String>> theStacks = new ArrayList<>();
```